# Limit the number of Excel rows

Tags: python, pandas

Given the example:

```
import pandas as pd

def multiple_dfs(sheet, row=0):

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter("testing.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(['Title'])
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice', 'Robert', 'John', 'Joe', 'Jordan'], 
                       'income': [40000, 50000, 42000, 25000, 2000000, 12000, 32000]})

    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet, startrow=row, header=None, \
                 index=False)
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet, startrow=row+2, index=False)

    writer.save()
    writer.close()

    style_dfs(df1)

multiple_dfs('aaa')
```

For `dfs`, I would like to limit the number of Excel rows to 5.

Is it possible to do such thing with pandas?

Comment: I understand, but if you want to create a full answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

To limit the number of rows exported to excel, you can use [`pandas.Dataframe.head()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.head.html) like:

```
df.head(5).to_excel(...)
```